# How can I insert an image into a PDF while keeping the form fields editable using PHP?

Tags: php, image, forms, pdf

I'm trying to insert an image of a signature into a PDF while keeping PDF's form fields editable while using PHP. Firstly, the form fields will have data in them already. I need to keep those filled form fields. Once the signature image is inserted into the PDF, how could I have the form fields hold their values and still be editable?

Could I use your solution to EDIT an existing PDF (not create a new one from scratch)? All I need to do is insert the signature image into an existing PDF. Also I need to position the image on the page.

I've tried TCPDF, fpdf, Imagick, and FPDI, but all they do is "flatten" the PDF (removes the editable form fields and returns images of the PDF).

I need the existing PDF to stay intact and the signature image to be positioned onto one of the existing PDF pages.

Here's the Imagick code that works but flattens the PDF:

```
        $existingPdfPath = \config::tempDir . '/existingFilledPDF.pdf';
        $pdf = new Imagick();
        $pdf->readImage($existingPdfPath);
        $pdf->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
        $pdf->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
        $pdf->setImageFormat('pdf');

        $signatureImagePath = \config::tempDir . '/signature.png';
        $signatureImage = new Imagick($signatureImagePath);
        
        $newWidth = 180;
        $newHeight = 30;

        $signatureImage->resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);

        $x = 295;
        $y = 610;

        foreach ($pdf as $int => $page) {
            if ($int == 1) {
                $page->compositeImage($signatureImage, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $x, $y);
            }
        }

        $outputPath = \config::tempDir . '/signedpdfoutput.pdf';
        $pdf->writeImages($outputPath, true);
```

Comment: `cpdf -stamp-on signature.pdf file.pdf 13 -o out.pdf` to stamp the signature `signature.pdf` onto `out.pdf` should preserve the form. If it doesn't, that's a bug, and I would welcome a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

We (I'm associated to Setasign) offer a PHP tool called [SetaPDF-Stamper](https://www.setasign.com/stamper) (not free) that allows you to stamp e.g. images onto existing PDFs. This also works with PDF forms (aka AcroForms). A simple demo would look like:

```
<?php

// load and register the autoload function
require_once '/path/to/SetaPDF/Autoload.php';

// create a writer
$writer = new SetaPDF_Core_Writer_Http('pdf-form-stamped.pdf', true);
// get a document instance
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename(
    'path/to/Order-Form-without-Signaturefield.pdf',
    $writer
);

// create a stamper instance
$stamper = new SetaPDF_Stamper($document);

// get an image instance
$image = SetaPDF_Core_Image::getByPath('path/to/Handwritten-Signature.png');
// initiate the stamp
$stamp = new SetaPDF_Stamper_Stamp_Image($image);
// set height (and width until no setWidth is set the ratio will retain)
$stamp->setHeight(40);

// add stamp to stamper on position right bottom for page 1 with a specific translation
$stamper->addStamp($stamp, [
    'position' => SetaPDF_Stamper::POSITION_RIGHT_BOTTOM,
    'showOnPage' => 1,
    'translateX' => -130,
    'translateY' => 60
]);

// stamp the document
$stamper->stamp();

// save and send it to the client
$document->save()->finish();
```

A working demo of this code is available in our [demo environment](https://demos.setasign.com/?p=%2Fdemo%2F6-Stamper%2F1-stamp-types%2F2-image-stamp%2F2-on-pdf-form).